# Include not working after upgrade php 5.3.3 to 5.6.30

Tags: php, include

I'd like to upgrade the version of PHP I'm using for my website.  I'm currently using 5.3.3 and have managed to install 5.6.30 (so I can run better PHP code to do cooler things!).

When I switch over to 5.6 the include files on my pages don't work at all.  When I look at the source code it shows the PHP code for the include instead of the code the include file should show.

For example it shows this in the page source:

```
<? include ("../bobs-house/new_website_top.php");?>
```

None of the includes work so I doubt it has anything to do with their contents.

I've tried using absolute file paths but that doesn't work.

I'm using Plesk v12.0.18 on CentOS 6.8 - I'm note sure what else you'll need to know.

Thanks in advance,

Jon

Comment: It sounds like your upgrade changed the short tags option. Change `<?` to `<?php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have a trouble with the short tag configuration
If you don't want to change all of your code replacing `<? ?> to <?php ?>`, you can change php.ini in the line

> short_open_tag=On

And restart Apache

Comment: Perfect, thank you for looking at this for me.  I'm very happy it was a simple fix!